# How to change structure of a JSON using php?

Tags: php, json

After I fetch data from my database,my result look like below in JSON format:

```
"return_data": {
    "friend_info": [
        {
            "desc": "name",
            "value": "Ken"
        },
        {
            "desc": "profile_pic",
            "value": "http://aaa.caa/1234569/picture?type=large"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to make the JSON look like:

```
"return_data": {
    "friend_info": [
        {
            "name": "Ken",
            "profile_pic": "http://aaa.caa/1234569/picture?type=large"
        }
     ]
}
```

But I totally have no idea,how to make it like above structure.Somebody please let me know the right direction,like what function I should use and so on..Thanks

Comment: you should enter your logic that you have tried on your end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert json to php array using `json_decode()` and get target value and insert into new object with custom structure and then replace new value into json array. At the end convert json array to string using `json_encode()`

```
$json = json_decode($jsonStr, true);
$obj = new stdClass;
foreach ($json["return_data"]["friend_info"] as $item)
    $obj->{$item["desc"]} = $item["value"];

$json["return_data"]["friend_info"] = $obj;
$jsonStr = json_encode($json);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/l7qdZ)

Note that json you shown isn't valid and should wrapped into `{}`